# VB.Net Image is not Showing at Runtime

Tags: vb.net, image, icons, runtime

Button image and icon is not showing at runtime

**Button Image**

```
Me.wibtnAdd.AccessibleRole = System.Windows.Forms.AccessibleRole.PushButton
Me.wibtnAdd.DisabledImagesGrayScale = False
Me.wibtnAdd.Enabled = False
Me.wibtnAdd.Image = CType(resources.GetObject("wibtnAdd.Image"), System.Drawing.Image)
Me.wibtnAdd.ImageFixedSize = New System.Drawing.Size(24, 24)
Me.wibtnAdd.ImagePosition = DevComponents.DotNetBar.eImagePosition.Top
Me.wibtnAdd.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(53, 302)
Me.wibtnAdd.Name = "wibtnAdd"
Me.wibtnAdd.Shape = New DevComponents.DotNetBar.RoundRectangleShapeDescriptor(2)
Me.wibtnAdd.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(61, 52)
Me.wibtnAdd.Style = DevComponents.DotNetBar.eDotNetBarStyle.StyleManagerControlled
Me.wibtnAdd.TabIndex = 8
Me.wibtnAdd.Text = "Add"
```

**Form Icon**

```
  Me.Icon = CType(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon"), System.Drawing.Icon)
```

Answer (score 0):

to make your code more clear : 1) get rid of the 'Me'
                               2) use a 'With' clause
(i edited)

the issue seems to be in your access to resources : are you sure
you have a resource named "wibtnAdd.Image" ? it seems 'strange'
that it has same name as your object/property... Check your 
wibtnAdd.Image, it might be Nothing. Same for your Icon.

Btw why not doing this in xaml ?? it would be much more readable,
and you can edit everything while seeing results.

Comment: http://www.wpftutorial.net/Home.html was my starting site. good to begin with, but useless when you become more advanced. switchonthecode has great tutorial also, and they give you a hint into more advanced xaml/xpf (http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials). And many more i guess.

Comment: still not working zzz.. i think the form has a problem because when i paste a working button with image in the form, in runtime the image will not show up here is the code of my form http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9153815/frmadd.txt

Comment: i know almost nothing about winform, execept no-one should use it unless threatened by a gun. If it is *your* project, go for a wpf application : faster better easier.